# Is There *Any* Way To Increase Internal Memory?

Tags: motorola-droid, customization, internal-storage

Ok, even to me this question sounds stupid but I let's just go with "the only dumb question is the one not asked".

I have nearly 14Gb free on my SD card but the Motorola Droid only has 128Mb internal so I am constantly fighting "low memory" warnings.  I have moved every app that I can to my SD card.  This is not only a hassle, for some apps (*cough*AnythingGoogle*cough*) I have to choose to either have Widget functionality or sacrifice my precious internal space.

**Question**: Is it physically possible for me to upgrade this internal memory?
Although I believe answering that question will cure my woes, I will open it further to ask: Do you have a recommendation on what I could do differently (other than *just delete your crap!*).  As I said, I have plenty of (SD) space so I find it asinine to have to make sacrifices because of these short-sights in this phone's design (after all, who would *ever* have an app larger than 1k, right?  You'll never come close to using 128Mb...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, of course, you could modify your hardware.  But this is not remotely feasible for 99% of us.

One thing you can do -- if you root -- is to install various apps that will allow you to move *more* to the SD card.  You could also try a custom ROM that is smaller than the stock ROM.  If rooted you will also be able to uninstall crapware system apps (be careful not to touch the important onces).

Comment: I actually removed my crapware (the **only** reason I root in the first place).  I did find an app to move any application to the SD card, but some of the larger ones (like Google Maps) I'm stuck leaving on internal or I'll lose widget capability.  Is there a way around this?  I know it was implemented for security reasons but I'm running out of options.  Even still it looks like most of my internal space isn't taken up by apps, but stuff like contacts, etc.  I'll have to dig a little deeper to see exactly how it pans out.

Comment: @Fantabulum I believe you can do some fancy partitioning/mounting/aliasing to make Android think that the SD card is internal storage instead of external, but that's risky and I can't find where I read how to do it.  As well it would cause a lot of apps to stop working anyways -- Android initializes services before the SD card is mounted, so apps with services would break.  You could try this in a terminal app on your phone: `su` then `pm setInstallLocation 2`. That will set the default install location to external storage, and may let you move a few more apps.

Comment: There are ways to get *all* of your installed apps to the SD Card, but often they include the need to run a 3rd-party custom firmware, and having to re-partition your SD Card.  Take a look at S2E (https://market.android.com/details?id=ru.krikun.s2e ) and DarkTremor (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=715940 )

Comment: @Gary Link2sd will help you move more to sd card at the same time preserves any "widget" functionality. It is the app that you are looking for!