# Increase internal storage of android device

Tags: cyanogenmod, internal-storage

I have 178MB on internal storage and I'm out of space, currently I have installed CM 10.1 and I want to know what choices do I have to get more space to install new applications, removing applications is not an option and deleting junk files either. I count with a 2gb sd card and I have heard that switching sd with phone internal storage is possible. What tool do you recommend?

Comment: You can't "increase internal storage". But you can take a look at [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2065/16575), our [internal-storage tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/internal-storage/info), and our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), to name some examples. Additionally, take a look at the questions linked in the "Related" section of your question, e.g. [Is There *Any* Way To Increase Internal Memory?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12273/16575?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two kind of solutions. One is to repartition, as you don't mentioned what kind of Android powered Smartphone you have I will try to get deep and the other to move apps to microSD (please read below).

1. If your device has a MediaTek cpu you can try Meteos Tool for repartitioning, you can find some details here http://www.modaco.com/topic/365701-re-partition-any-mtk6589-phone-without-a-pc-more-data-storage/. This application can be used on the smartphone and repartition the memory to different sizes depending on the selection of the user and the limit of the memory itself. I have used it, it's very easy to be implemented.
2. The other solution is to use something that is called Link2SD. This although is not repartitioning the memory, it moves every app even other files to the microSD memory (there are solutions to run the whole ROM from the microSD) and have free space at the smartphone     memory. This way it solves the problem of the internal low memory.