# Unable to install app on Micromax A106

Tags: google-play-store, installation, insufficient-memory, micromax

I'm unable to install an app on Micromax A106. It shows sufficient space in storage, but an error comes out as not enough space.

Answer (score 0):

This phone seems to have very little space for files. As you don't mention how much space has left for a user to install apps I will think it is too low to be any useful to any kind of user. The only real choices, that can work in this kind of situation, are the two I am describing in this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/79017/increase-internal-storage-of-android-device/79033#79033).

Be aware that these two solutions have as a requirement for the phone to be rooted. If these two solutions do not fit you, you can always try to uninstall big apps from your phone and install smaller ones that do the same job.